# Add 2 values to post__not_in

Tags: loop, array

How can I add to values to the post__not_in function?

For example, I want to exclude $value1 and $value2 from a loop

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should display 5 posts per page (-1 for all of them on one page), with the post ID's $value1 and $value2 being ignored. Ensure $value1 and $value2 are integers.

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 5,
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post__not_in' => array(
        $value1,
        $value2
    )
);
query_posts($args);
```

EDIT - With the further informaiton below, and based on the code from that site, try this -

Loop 1 -

```
<?php
query_posts('showposts=8');
$ids = array();
while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    $ids[] = get_the_ID();
    the_title();
    the_content();
endwhile;
?>
```

Loop 2 -

```
<?php
query_posts(array('post__not_in' => $ids));
while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    $ids[] = get_the_ID();
    the_title();
    the_content();
endwhile;
?>
```

Loop 3 -

```
<?php
query_posts(array('post__not_in' => $ids));
while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_title();
    the_content();
endwhile;
?>
```

Important notes - Make sure you do not redeclare the `$ids` array in loop 2 or 3, as this will overwrite the previous array and creat a new, blank one. Also, ensure that you add the IDs from the second loop to `$ids` so that loop 3 knows what to exclude.

Comment: That didn't seem to help. I'm using a code I found here - http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/10/10-useful-wordpress-loop-hacks/ It's number 2 in the list and it works fine if I only have 2 loops. But I have 3 and I want the third to exclude post ID's that have appeared in the first 2

Comment: @DeanElliott - See edits above.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot man, you've saved me a lot of grief

Comment: @DeanElliott - You are welcome.